# Do we know of any of Roronoa Zoro's family?

Tags: one-piece

I was watching some AMVs on YouTube and one of them mentioned the tragic familial backstory each character has:

- For Luffy, it was Ace, Sabo, Dragon, Garp, and Shanks
- For Usopp, it was Yasopp, Banchina, and Kaya
- For Nami, it was Bell-mère and Nojiko

Zoro is the only member of the Pre-Grandline crew that we know nothing (to my knowledge) of his family except for Koshiro and Kuina (they were the only thing close that I could think of).

Was there ever anything mentioned about Zoro's family?

Comment: You forgot Sanji? both don't have any family backstory as far as I remember, their family is Baratie Restaurant and Dojo. Bell-mère and Nojiko also not related by blood with Nami

Comment: Saji has his adopted cook father thing who lost his leg, and Zoro has his childhood rival that died. Maybe not family, but still important people that changed their lives

Comment: Oda-san only shows the relevant family to the story. Luffy's mother, Nami's father, Brook's family, Sanji's family have all gone unmentioned too. Therefore I doubt Zoro's family will every be introduced. They probably died when he was young anyway.

Comment: No, maybe not yet.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing has ever been shown of Zoro's family, and he has never mentioned them. We know from his flashback that he trained in Kuina's father's dojo from a reasonably young age, and that even before that he traveled around as a reasonably good swordsman.

There's a chance he might have family on Wano Kuni, but I think it's unlikely. We don't know if he knows his family, or if he grew up as an orphan, but he has been without a family for a long time now.

Answer (score 2):

Zoro is the son of Roronoa Arashi, who married a woman from East Blue.

Zoro’s father, Arashi, is the son of Shimotsuki Furiko and Roronoa Pinzoro, who were both natives of Wano Country, the land of the samurai.

Zoro’s grandmother, Furiko, is the elder sister of Shimotsuki Ushimaru, the former Daimyo of Ringo in Wano, who died fighting Kaido’s invasion.

Zoro’s grandfather, Pinzoro, is a descendant of Shimotsuki Kouzaburo, a legendary swordsmith who forged Enma, one of the swords of the former Shogun of Wano, Kozuki Oden.

Zoro’s ancestor, Kouzaburo, left Wano 55 years ago with a group of 25 people and settled in East Blue, where he founded Shimotsuki Village, the place where Zoro grew up and learned swordsmanship.

Zoro’s distant ancestor, Shimotsuki Ryuma, was a legendary samurai who was known as the “God of the Blade” and who once slayed a dragon in Wano. Zoro met Ryuma’s corpse in Thriller Bark, where he inherited his sword, Shusui, which he later returned to his grave in Wano.

Answer (score 1):

Like other Straw Hats, nothing about his biological family has been told yet.

Most of them had been raised by foster families (Dadan, Koshiro, Bellmere, Zeff, Kureha, Tom and so on) and I think Oda clearly tries to make point that family is not about blood, but about feelings.

Comment: On that note, what do we know about Oda-sama's parents?